# How to deploy an application for Blackberry Phone and Windows mobile

Tags: blackberry, windows-mobile, flex4.5

Can I create the Flex application for Windows Mobile and Blackberry phone and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point in time I do not believe that either are officially supported by Adobe. You can write apps for the BB Playbook, but not for their phones.